# Is it possible to open a console window while debugging a test in PhpStorm?

Tags: debugging, console, phpstorm

While debugging a test in PhpStorm, the console is taken over by the test results. Because of this I cannot execute functions with real time variables at a breakpoint. Is it possible to open another console window to be able do this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately interactive console is not available for tests at the moment.
*[June 2018]*

There is a request [Please implement interactive debug console while debugging a phpunit test](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-35950)  - *please vote for it as there are not so many votes*.